# How to run a Cron job for Node.js

Tags: unix, cron, node.js

I have a cron job that call a shell script.

```
*/2 * * * * sh cron_test.sh >> output.log
```

In side the shell script, I run some command lines like:

```
#!/usr/bin

./mongo/bin/mongodump .....

FILE_NAME='abc'

node mynode.js $FILENAME
```

It runs if I just call cron_test.sh in command prompt.  However, it doesn't run node if it is run by cronjob.  It does run the mongodump command.  So, what's wrong?  is there anything I have to set for permission, etc?

Comment: Are you sure it works from the commandline? I mean, you haven't defined the `FILENAME` variable.

Comment: You sure node is in the path of the user that cron is running under?

Comment: You do know that you've got 2 filename variables: `FILE_NAME` and `FILENAME` - right?

Comment: You should use a decent message queue instead of cronjobs if you ask me. Beanstalkd for example has delayed PUTS.

Comment: Change to cron entry to `*/2 * * * * cd WORKDIR && sh ./cron_test.sh >> output.log` where WORKDIR is the directory with the mongo subdir, also change the `node...` to `./node...` or `/fully/qualified/path/node...`. As macarthy pointed out, it is a common error to assume that cronjobs run within the same environment as a login shell provides, but this is not the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

thanks.. I find it out..

either I need to specify the node path or
do that in the sh script:

```
nodejs/node myscript.js
```

where nodejs/node is where the node installed.

Comment: Hallelujah. Thank you. I've been grappling that problem for hours.